# Random Sample by Group and Specific Probability Distribution for Groups

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have data set with all dates in 2021 and I would like to create random samples of repeating dates in each month. The distribution of dates within each month should follow a certain pattern that mirrors a specific percentage of day of the week. For example, I would like to generate 1000 dates from January 2021 and approximately 8% or 80 of these days should be Mondays. Please consider the following working example:

```
dt2021 <- 
  tibble(SalesDate = seq.Date(
    ymd("2021-01-01"), 
    ymd("2021-12-31"), 1)) %>%
  mutate(
    wkDay=weekdays(SalesDate),
    year=year(SalesDate), 
    month=month(SalesDate))
dt2021 %>% glimpse()

dtWkDays <- tibble(
  wkDay=c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
          "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
          "Sunday"),
  Freq=c(0.08, 0.07, 0.09, 0.12, 0.31, 0.32, 
         0.01))
dtWkDays
```

My pseudo script for what I am trying to do would look something like the following:

```
set.seed(123)
dt2021_01 <- dt2021 %>% filter(month==1) %>%  
    # generate a random sample of 1000 dates
    # use the wkday in dtWkDays for the grouping (stratification)
    # use the Freq in dtWkDays for the weights
    # resample = T
```

If the solution is correct, the following R script should produce around 80 Mondays, 70 Tuesdays, 90 Wednesdays, 120 Thursdays, etc.

```
dt2021_01 %>% count(wkDay)
```

I have tried several combinations using `slice_sample`, `sample_frac`, and `group_by`, `weight_by`, etc., and nothing has generated the correct results for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might work. Join the frequency tibble with your date tibble. After filtering for the month of interest, a revised frequency can be calculated based on frequency for day of the week, adjusting for number of times that day of the week appears in that month. Finally, use `slice_sample` with this new frequency included as `weight_by` (weights add up to 1, though they otherwise would be standardized to add up to 1 anyways).

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

dt2021 %>%
  filter(month == 1) %>%
  left_join(dtWkDays) %>%
  group_by(wkDay) %>%
  mutate(newFreq = Freq / n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1000, weight_by = newFreq, replace = TRUE) %>%
  count(wkDay)
```

**Output**

```
  wkDay         n
  <chr>     <int>
1 Friday      312
2 Monday       81
3 Saturday    320
4 Sunday       10
5 Thursday    120
6 Tuesday      62
7 Wednesday    95
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you help me understand the logic behind the creation of the new variable newFreq and its use in the slice_sample()

Comment: `newFreq` was created to consider the varying number of weekdays in a month.  For example, January 2021 has 5 Sundays, so given there are 5 possibilities for a different Sunday that month, the frequency of .01 was divided by 5 for each Sunday. Monday through Thursday only has 4 possibilities, so each of those date probabilities that month is divided by 4. Then `slice_sample` will sample from the whole month, with these new calculated individual probabilities for each day of the month. Let me know if this helps.